# Designed Form Select - onchange submit doesnt work

Tags: javascript, css, forms, onchange

in hard-work I created a selected form with images, correctly shown in Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer in compatibility mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
  <head>
    <title>InputEdit Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/standard.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inputedit.js"></script>  
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  </head>
  <body style="margin:30px;">
    <form action="form.php" method="post">
      <select id="sel_no1" name="sel_no1" class="inputEdit_select">
        <option value="1">Diese Woche</option>
        <option value="2">Diesen Monat</option>
        <option value="3">Hall of Fame</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I used the Javascript plugins from there:
[Download](http://blogfiles.ka-mediendesign.de/inputEdit.zip) They used MooTools, a JavaScript framework.

Now to my Problem:
when i want to use `onclick="this.form.submit();"` nothing happens.

Did anyone of you can get me a better use of an well designed select form with onchange submit? Or show me how can i solve my problem?

[Here I've uploaded](http://downloads.tm-attacks.de/inputEdit.zip) all my files with a preview. This problem I try to fix for a lot of hours. I hope some friendly guy would help me.

Regards
Robin

Comment: can you create a fiddle instead

Comment: Like btevfik said, i create a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/EJ8A6/2/

but it should run like: http://tm-attacks.de/inputedit/demo.html
and onchance it should submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just submit the form when the select box is changed, do this:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" id="theForm">
      <select id="sel_no1" name="sel_no1" class="inputEdit_select" onchange="document.getElementById('theForm').submit();">
        <option value="1">Diese Woche</option>
        <option value="2">Diesen Monat</option>
        <option value="3">Hall of Fame</option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I use this value, nothin happens. I think the motools javascript delete this action. I got no plan, why.